# Airfoil plot issue

Tags: matlab

I am having an issue with plotting my airfoil on matlab. It appears that there are some abberations with only one or two values. I have checked again and again with the formulas so they should be good. I have not converted to degrees so that's not the issue.

```
%% setup 
clc
clear all
%type of airfoil
typeNACA = '2312';

%extract values of airfoil type
M = str2double(typeNACA(1)); % max camber %chord
P = str2double(typeNACA(2)); % chordwise position
Thmax = str2double(typeNACA(3:4));

M=M/100;
P=P/100
Thmax=Thmax/100;


% gridpoints
gridpoints = 1000; 

% Airfoil grid
x = linspace(0,1,gridpoints);

%camber equations 
%yc1(x) = (M/P^2)*(2*P*x-x^2);
%yc(x) = (M/(1-P)^2*(1-2*P+2*Px-x^2); % (for P =< x <1)
%dyc1 = (2*M/P^2)*(P-x)
%dyc2 = (2*M)/(1-P^2)*(P-x)

%Camber and gradient
yc = ones(gridpoints,1);
dyc= ones(gridpoints,1);
theta=ones(gridpoints,1);
for i=1:gridpoints

    if (x(i) >= 0 && x(i) < P)
        yc(i) = (M/P^2)*(2*P*x(i)-x(i)^2); % (for 0 =< x < P)
        dyc(i)= ((2*M)/P^2)*(P - x(i)); %dyc/dx

    elseif (x(i) >= P && x(i) <= 1)  % (for P =< x <1)
        yc(i)=(M/(1-P)^2)*(1-2*P+2*P*x(i)-x(i)^2); 
        dyc(i) = (2*M)/((1-P)^2*(P-x(i)));
    end
    theta(i) = atan(dyc(i)); %angle theta
end


% thickness coefficients
a0 = 0.2969;
a1 = -0.126;
a2 = -0.3516;
a3 = 0.2843;
a4 = -0.1036;  % -0.1015 for open TE -0.1036 for closed TE

%thickness distribution 
yt = ones(gridpoints,1);
for i=1:1:gridpoints
  yt(i) = (Thmax/0.2)*(a0*x(i)^0.5 + a1*x(i) + a2*x(i)^2 + a3*x(i)^3 + a4*x(i)^4);
end

% Upper surface points
xu = ones(gridpoints,1);
yu = ones(gridpoints,1);
for i= 1:gridpoints
    xu(i) = x(i) - yt(i)*sin(theta(i));
    yu(i) = yc(i) + yt(i)*cos(theta(i));
end

% Lower surface points
xl = ones(gridpoints,1);
yl = ones(gridpoints,1);
for i=1:1:gridpoints
    xl(i) = x(i) + yt(i)*sin(theta(i));
    yl(i) = yc(i) - yt(i)*cos(theta(i));
end

%PLOT
f1 = figure(1);
hold on; grid on;
axis equal
plot(xu,yu,'r';
plot(xl,yl,'b');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well! The first problem is you've forgotten the closing parenthesis in the second line from the end. But if you want me to check your code, I need to have your typeNACA() function .m file to revise it. Or u can post its code here.

```
%PLOT
f1 = figure(1);
hold on; grid on;
axis equal
plot(xu,yu,'r';
plot(xl,yl,'b');
```